# Display start page when opening a Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, is it possible to display a start/welcome page when opening a solution file?

I'd like to have some way to show build information to new developers joining the team.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already considered writing your own extension for Visual Studio?
Soma Somasegar has pointed out where to start in [his blog here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2009/12/09/creating-extensions-for-vs-2010.aspx).

You will need to install the [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2680) (online documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441%28VS.100%29.aspx)) from [samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx) at MSDN.

I have not done this myself yet, but I know that you can create tool windows that already load with Visual Studio. You can request a notification when a solution is loaded and then execute your own custom code.

(I just read about the notfications yesterday in [Rico Mariani's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/12/visual-studio-11-beta-performance-part-2.aspx)).

Should be possible. :-)

Comment: Yeah. I considered writing one (actually a macro should do the job, but I've done a source control provider before...), but I wondered whether one already existed.

Comment: I wrote one back in 2013: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RogerLipscombe.WelcomePage; I've no idea whether it works with the latest VS. Code's at https://github.com/rlipscombe/vs-welcome-page, if anyone wants to adopt it.